# Java Programing about HTMLEditorKit

Tags: java, html, css

My source code is below.

I want to control font color only css.

I insert HTML like this.

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple</span></span><span class="tag2"> pie</span>.
```

In case of tag1, I expect "I love apple" turns red font.

But only "I love" turns red font.

How do I fix it　??

```
    doc.getStyleSheet().addRule(".tag1 {color : red;}");

    try {

        kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<span class=\"tag1\">I love <span class=\"tag2\">apple</span></span><span class=\"tag2\"> pie</span>.", 0, 0, null);
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you write properties of each class?
i mean `tag1` and `tag1`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you set red color to `.tag1` only, when `<span class="tag2">apple</span>` is a `span` inside `.tag1`, so it doesn't get the color css attribute directly.
As @hoosssein said, if you have a default (or any) css color value for span, it won't use the parent's style, and this is what happens here.

You need to add:

```
doc.getStyleSheet().addRule(".tag1 span {color : red;}");
```

So every span inside .tag1 cls will also have red color.

Comment: Does it means "doc.getStyleSheet().addRule(".tag1 span {color : red;}");" ??

Comment: it is incorrect. if I have element A inside element B, all properties of element B that are not specified in A will inherit to element A if it was possible